# Cлово "вселенная": можно ли писать со строчной буквы?

Tags: орфография

Cлово "вселенная": можно ли -  и когда - писать со строчной буквы?

Answer (score 2):

*"Вселенная"* пишется с *маленькой буквы:*

- в словосочетаниях *"на всю вселенную", "вся вселенная"*;
- в значении *"не наша Вселенная, а другая",* часто фантастическая;
- в переносном смысле, или в значении *"мирок", "мир".*

В последнем значении нашёл в Нацкорпусе:

> А сзади них громоздилась несложная ***вселенная*** поставщика его императорского величества, его фамилия и звание золотой загогулиной вились внизу паспарту, все эти зеркала, пальмы в кадочках, пни из папье-маше и, наконец, нарисованный на холсте дремучий лес и луна среди косматых вершин. [Ю. О. Домбровский. Факультет ненужных вещей, часть 5 (1978)]